# How can I know which parameter is causing: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-functions

I am using VB.net to connect to Oracle Database, and call a function that resides inside a package.

The function expects a huge number of parameters (56 parameters to be exact). And it returns a BOOLEAN.

Out of 56 parameters, 55 of them are `InputOutpt` and the first one is `Input` only.
The purpose of the function is to look up a table based on the value of the first `Input` parameter and if found then the remaining 55 parameters will be assigned values from the table, then the function will return `TRUE`. If not, then the function will return `FALSE`.

The problem I am having now is `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` throws an Exception:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I did everything I could to detect which parameter of the 56 is causing the exception, but had no luck.

I mapped each parameter of type `NUMBER` in oracle to `OracleDbType.Decimal`

likewise, each `VARCHAR2` parameter was used as `OracleDbType.Varchar2`

The first parameter is of type `PLS_INTEGER` so I used `OracleDbType.Int16`

I called the procedure with an additional parameter of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` for the function's return value, and set its type to `OracleDbType.Decimal` and its `size = 1`

I added the parameters to the `OracleCommand` in the same order they are defined in the function. Because the list of parameter is huge, I will list a few of them here:

```
Dim p_index As New OracleParameter(":index", OracleDbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.Input) 

'[:index] is the same parameter name used to define the oracle function
```

What is the best way to locate the source of the exception?
I switched between `Decimal` and `Double` but that did not solve the problem.
I also tried `Int16` for the return value instead of `Decimal` but again, no luck.

Comment: Maybe you should change your function. Make one input parameter and return one RecordSet with 55 columns (and max. 1 row). You can check the result for `.COUNT() > 0` to get the same information.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the function is used by other programmers and changing its logic might cause other problems. I just want to know if there is something wrong I am doing

Comment: `PLS_INTEGER` is a 32 bit number, range of -2^31 to 2^31. Better use `Int32` for it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. I changed my code from `Int16` to `Int32` but I still get the same message. Maybe there is something else